# Using referrerPolicy in a video tag

Tags: html, same-origin-policy, referrer

i am currently building an app on react (i don't think it's relevant) and i have to use data from other websites.

First a picture, and then a video : i could block the referrer on the image tag

`<img referrerPolicy="no-referrer" src="https://website/resource.jpg"></img>`

, which is working perfectly.

On the video tag, however, i couldn't block it as the tag doesn't support this attribute,

```
<video id='video' controls  preload='metadata'>
            <source src="https://website/video.mp4" type='video/mp4'/>
        </video>
```

and adding

```
 <meta name="referer" content="no-referrer" />
```

in the header of my index.html was unfruitful as well.

Any ideas ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see on for example https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy only the HTTP-header is the one miss-spelled with only one r.

They have an example:

```
<meta name="referrer" content="origin">
```

(But you wanted no-referrer instead of origin)

Some more info:
Relevant warning from the same page but you seem to have done that one right.

> Warning: As seen above, the noreferrer link relation is written
> without a dash — noreferrer. When the referrer policy is specified for
> the entire document with a  element, it's written with a dash:
> .